# ECLIPSE comments in Android code - what is this?

Tags: android, eclipse

I was just writing my code and put a `// TODO:` comment line, so I don't forget then on the left side a unknown little icon appears.

Does anyone know what this means and how to use this? I could not find anything about this extra feature thingy. Are there more of these? Can one search for "TODOs" somehow?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](http://madharasan.wordpress.com/2009/05/19/eclipsetodo/) link should help explain it.

To view the added tasks, you have to open the Tasks window, which is different from the Task List Window. To open the Tasks window:

> window -> show view -> other… > general > tasks

If you don’t see general, try typing “**task**” in the filter text box.

Comment: hey, that's really cool - in xCode I always write my xxx and search for it :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create a class with an implemented method usually eclipse will fill it in for you (the unimplemented methods) and it creates the methods and puts that comment in there (it's auto-generated and a method stub)

You can make those To-do blocks yourself as a reminder for unimplemented / not completed methods. If you want to work on an old project you can just check the scrollbar and see for any blue bars so you know you haven't implemented some methods yet and implement them.

Answer (score 0):

Press Window->Show view->Tasks.
This bookmark show all your TODO and another comments marks for your project/workspace

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is the reason, but I noticed the feature stopped
working sometime after this was announced:

[check this](http://news.com.com/Microsoft+checks...3-5228693.html)

[also this post](http://www.theinquirer.net/?article=16489)

[and this post](http://www.flipcode.com/cgi-bin/fcms...ead_show=22715)

this may help you

Comment: hello jigar bhai..the above links you posted only one the second link is working others are not working can you edit that and correct it.